# How to set a time using JavaScript pickatime library

Tags: javascript, timepicker

I'm using http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/ library to config an input field as a time picker:

```
<input type="text" class="pickatime" name="startTime" id="startTime">
```

Then I started the picker time using:

```
var pickerStart;
function setStartTime()
{
    pickerStart = $('#startTimeEdit').pickatime({
        interval: 15,
        min: [5,30],
        max: [23,0],
        formatSubmit: 'HH:i',
        hiddenName: true
    });
    pickerStart.set('select', '08:30', { format: 'hh:i' });
}
```

But I can't find a way to set the time after the picker is initialize.

Is there a way to restart it or set its value?

The documentation is not clear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the API, you should first store the picker in a variable

```
var picker = $('#startTimeEdit').pickatime().pickatime('picker')
```

Then you will be able to call methods on this variable. In order to set a particular time you can use below method :

```
//setting random date
picker.set('select', [2015, 3, 20])

//setting current date
picker.set('select', new Date())

// Using arrays formatted as [HOUR,MINUTE].
picker.set('select', [3,0])

// Using a string along with the parsing format (defaults to `format` option).
picker.set('select', '04-30', { format: 'hh-i' })
```

Comment: thans for answering: I edited the question cause the set method is not working

Comment: **pickerStart.set('select', '08:30', { format: 'hh:i' });** this will not work. **pickerStart** is an object of your whole control, so first you need to get the picker out of it by calling **pickatime('picker')** function on that then you can call set methos, so the set line should go like this **pickerStart.pickatime('picker').set('select', '08:30', { format: 'hh:i' });**